# Is it possible to trigger process death scenario in an android instrumentation test?

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, android-instrumentation

Google didn't help and I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this with android instrumentation tests

```kotlin
class TestWithActivity {
  @get:Rule
  val composeRule: TestActivityRule = createAndroidComposeRule()

  @Test
  fun testStateRestorationAfterProcessDeath(): Unit = with(composeRule) {
    // Way to kill and restart the app process here
  }
}
```